# Overcome node.js memory limit with fork() ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to my knowledge most node.js versions have memory limit for each process around 1GB, based on this information:

> Currently, by default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit systems, and 1.4GB on 64-bit systems.
>   https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/FAQ

It is an old archive, things may have improved since. However, what I am interested about is if one is about to use

```
require('child_process').fork("newProcess.js")
```

Is it possible to overcome this limitation?

Thus creating a new V8 instance would create a new memory pool for JavaScript Objects.

The reason I am asking is that I could not find a reliable source exactly confirming this case, even though the documentation strongly suggests that this would be the case because it states:

> These child Node.js processes are still whole new instances of V8.

Comment: Afaik it's just a parameter passed at startup to override the default

Comment: ah, you mean the default memory size ? What I am interested mostly is the behaviour of fork() - it would also enable multicore support, but memory limit might prevent utilizing that

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question, you want to fork() with a different memory limit (`--max-old-space-size` parameter). By default, the new nodeJS instance will inherit this from the parent.

However, you can bypass this limitation passing parameters to the forked() instance like this:

```js
require('child_process').fork("newProcess.js", { 
        execArgv: ['--max-old-space-size=4096']
    });)
```

This will fork your process but with a 4Gb memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

`node --max-old-space-size=4096` should work.

AFAIK the limit is depending on V8's buffer size. `fork()` can of course handle bigger data as long as you don't hold all of it in a buffer.

Comment: I do not see how this answer is helping to determine whether the fork() creates a new memory pool for JS objects or not

Comment: Well your questios is how you can overcome memory limits. Memory pools would be a detail of implementation, that might not even necessarily have a causal relation to V8, but might be triggered by `libuv`.

Another question would be: does V8 have memory pools? -> likely. If there is a new instance created on fork, then, yes, there is a new memory pool.

Comment: Again: this question has nothing to do with overcoming memory limits in node.js but how the fork() does behave - is there a new V8 instance with JS Object heap or not.

Comment: Then please change the title of your question.

Comment: I agree with elje, your question title is misleading @TeroTolonen

Comment: @Glstunna it should not be so misleading - the "title"  clearly states that the method looked after is using fork(), and that implies using inter-process communication. The reason I'm asking is that I have written inter-process communication library, which serializes the method calls to other processes, but there is no advantage doing so if no new memory pool has been allocated.

Comment: Do you have the sources on GitHub? You would probably be the first one to do so.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe sure, you can take a look on them here; https://github.com/terotests/Marx

Comment: Originally I created the solution for instantiating objects inside the Web Workers - how to serialize calls for some specific instance for additional calculation like parsing AST trees, but it was quite straighforward to implement at node.js  processes - sorry for the poor documentation @github, it was just a side project created along the way

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to Boriel's answer, but better (IMHO).

Passing the node option --max-old-space-size through the environment allows you to invoke ".js" files directly.

```
var env = Object.assign({ 'NODE_OPTIONS' : '--max-old-space-size=4096' }, process.env );
require('child_process').fork("newProcess.js", { env: env });
```

Please note that if you were already using some node options when running the original program, you would have to concat this option to the existing ones.